# Reactivating WordPress Jetpack plugin throws an error

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I am getting the following error when trying to re-activate Jetpack plugin:

> Invalid request, please go back and try again.
>
> Error Code:invalid_client
>
> Error Message: Unknown client_id.

Comment: I updated the tags and the title to better reflect your question. I have removed the part out the self answered part as its implied by your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

1. Deactivate and Delete Jetpack plugin
2. Go to your PHPMyAdmin
3. Run the SQL Query : `` SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%jetpack_%' ``
4. Delete the items that start with the option_name `jetpack_`
5. Download and Install Jetpack.

You should now be able to connect JetPack without any errors.

Comment: Please select this as the accepted answer as you self answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to sign in to your Wordpress.com account before connecting jetpack to wordpress. Doing so resolved this issue for me.

Comment: This looked like it worked but in fact I still get unknown_token: It looks like your Jetpack connection is broken. Try disconnecting from WordPress.com then reconnecting.